# Oracle: Permissions to dir

Tags: oracle, plsql

I run the write_test procedure, which works good.

```
begin
    koll_data_pkg.write_test(p_customer_id=>247, p_addr=>'address', p_dir=>'\\SERVER01\Backup\Log\');
end;
```

But, when I change value of p_dir to another directory p_dir=>\SERVER12\Backup\Log\ it gives following error:

```
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: by "SYS.UTL_FILE", 
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: by "DATA_PKG", 
ORA-06512: by line
```

I have tried give permission using following commands, but still same error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DEVO_INVREC_DIR AS '\\SERVER12\Backup\Log\';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY DEVO_INVREC_DIR TO USER1;
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY DEVO_INVREC_DIR TO USER1;
GRANT EXECUTE ON UTL_FILE TO USER1;
```

Procedure:

```
procedure write_test(p_customer_id in koll_customer_party.customer_id%type,
                                 p_addr in varchar,
                                 p_dir in varchar,
                                 p_filename in varchar2 default null)
   is
       lt_id       id_tt;
       lt_bolagsnamn    bolagsnamn_tt;
       l_file           utl_file.file_type;
       l_line           varchar2(2048);
       l_name           varchar2(300):= 'DEVO_INVREC_DIR';
       l_filename       varchar2(100):= 'testfile.txt';
       l_sql            varchar2(512);
   begin

       select devo_id, bolagsnamn
          bulk collect into lt_id, lt_bolagsnamn
          from documents where customer_id=p_customer_id

       if lt_id.count > 0 then
            l_sql := 'create or replace directory ' || l_name || ' as ''' || p_dir || '''';
            execute immediate l_sql;

            if p_filename is not null then
                l_filename := p_filename;
            end if;
            l_file := utl_file.fopen(l_name,l_filename,'w');

            if utl_file.is_open(l_file) is not null then
               for i in lt_id.first .. lt_devo_id.last loop      
                    l_line:= lt_id(i) || ';' || replace(lt_bolagsnamn(i),';','');
                    utl_file.put_line(l_file, l_line);
               end loop;
            end if;
            utl_file.fclose(l_file);
       end if;
end;
```

Comment: So is `\\SERVER12\Backup\Log` a directory which is on the database server (or at least mapped to it)? Is it a directory on which the account which owns the Oracle installation has privileges?

Comment: @APC: It is a mapped directory. I have tried z:\Backup\Log as well but does not work.

Comment: And have you checked the permissions on the shared drive? Which users are checked in the Advanced Sharing/Permissions dialogue?

Comment: Yes it has all permissions that the directory has which is accessible from oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this forum response: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4145239?start=0&tstart=0

In summary, Oracle can't access the network shares in its default installed configuration because the Windows SYSTEM user can't access network shares by definition. You either have to reconfigure Oracle to run as a user other than SYSTEM, with permissions on the share, or allow SYSTEM to access network shares (a HUGE security risk). I was going to include a link describing how to change the user to be another service account, but they all seem to be broken or removed. It may depend on your exact version of Oracle and Windows, too, so you're best bet in the absence of other documentation would be to contact Oracle Support. There is no simple PL/SQL programming answer to your problem.